# How do I translate "perfectionist"?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

How can I translate *perfectionist* in Esperanto? It is tempting to say *perfektisto*, but since this is a personal trait and not a profession I'm sure that would be incorrect. What about *perfektemulo*? Or does that describe a person who is perfect? That is certainly not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9):

*perfektemulo* is the most natural to me. Someone who likes to be perfect. Moreover the *-emulo* phraze is really very Esperantesque.

Answer (score 4):

The suffix *-isto* is not limited to profession, it can also imply a vocation, see *Esperantisto* or *naciisto*.

However, since you want to describe a trait, *perfektemulo* is a good choice. If you want/need to be more precise, you can coin *perfektigemulo* = individual with the inclination to make things perfect.

I can't find any occurrences of *perfektisto*, *perfektemulo* or *perfektigemulo* in tekstaro.com. I got *troigemulo* and *mortigemulo* (once each) which are also built with *-ig-em-ul-o*.

Answer (score 3):

Mi ĉiam diras ke mi estas "perfektema" por *perfectionist tendencies*… Certe "perfektemulo" bone funkcias.

Mi trovis uzon de tiu vorto en la Fejsbuka grupo: "Mi estas [perfektemulo](https://www.facebook.com/groups/duolingo.esperanto.learners/search/?query=perfektemulo)".